# Cracking transposition cipher

Tags: encryption, classical-cipher, playfair

I have a task to decrypt custom made transposition cipher, as I'm not the cryptography expert, I would appreciate any help.

I've been given the table of characters ...

```
M A N B C
D E F G H
I K L O P
Q R S T U
V W X Y Z
```

... with images representing:

- swap
- up twice
- left twice

(There's no word about the order of these steps)

The hints are:

1. `MAN`
2. `NP = CL`

Texts to decode is: `ET KO KF`

---

I've tried to fit the steps for getting `CL` out of `NP`, but with no luck. Also, there's no sign if the characters are "pushed" while making steps, or the character we're moving is being swapped with the next letter (I'm not even sure if we're moving characters or columns or something else). I know it might seem not explained enough, but as I'm not an expert, I wanted to ask you as it might be some known pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a [Playfair cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher) with `MAN` as the key.

For characters not in the same row / column, you make a rectangle with the encoded characters at the corners, and the characters in the same row on the opposing sides of the rectangle form the decoded letters. For `NP` we have -

```
[N]--B-->C
 F   G   H
 L<--O--[P]
```

Which yields `CL`.

---

So for `ET` we have -

```
[E]--F-->G
 K   L   O
 R<--S--[T]
```

Decoding to `GR`.

For `KO` we need a new rule, since `K` and `O` are on the same row. For items on the same row we simply shift each letter left one position, wrapping back to the start of the row if needed. This means `KO` yields

```
I<--[K] L<--[O]
```

In other words, `KO` -> `IL`.

Finally for `KF` we have -

```
 E<--[F]
[K]-->L
```

Which yields `LE`

So `ET KO KF` gives us `GRILLE`.

Comment: That is correct. Thank you for your help. I can't imagine myself understanding what I've written better than you :D